# Different layout and phtml for types of simple product

Tags: layout, template

It is possible to define a different template in my layout xml for simple products that are a child of a grouped product compared to a stand-alone simple product?

In my current store the "child" products pull information from the parent which obviously cannot be the case for stand-alone products.  The only other alternative I can see is to put a whole load of IFs all over the place based on whether the product has a parent  using  `getParentIdsByChild($product->getId())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new layout handle, let's call it `<product_child_of_grouped>` that you can load only if the product is part of a grouped product.
in your `product_child_of_grouped` layout handle you can do this:

```
<product_child_of_grouped>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>path/to/template.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</product_child_of_grouped>
```

Then you can rewrite the method `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View::initProductLayout()` and tell Magento to load your layout handle if the product is part of a grouped product.

after the line `$update->addHandle('PRODUCT_' . $product->getId());` add this

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'simple') {
    $parentGrouped = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_link')
            ->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_GROUPED);
    if ($count($parentGrouped)) {
        $update->addHandle('product_child_of_grouped');
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers Marius good tip. I think that is the best way to achieve it. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: You can add layout handles via `controller_action_layout_load_before` event. No rewrite necessary. See [Creating Custom Layout Handles](http://magebase.com/?p=1402) for more information.

Comment: @mam08ixo. I agree, but that event gets dispathced for all the pages. There is no point in adding an overhead on every page just to check if the current product is grouped.